# Should "baby" be capitalized when placed before a name?

Tags: capitalization

Can *baby* ever be used as a title? In the sentence, "I thought baby Cora was such a cute infant!" should *baby* be capitalized? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can - for a not-yet-named infant (Baby Smith) or a young child given anonymity in a court case (Baby S). I don't think there's a rule for whether it should be capitalised in a sentence such as yours.

Comment: @KateBunting It's reasonable to think that it could be by analogy with the naming of relatives (Uncle Jim, Great-Aunt Mary, Cousin Jane and so on). I don't think most people would mind whether you capitalised it or not, they'd be too busy cooing over Cora.

Comment: @KateBunting If you were writing the sentence, would you go with capitalization here?

Comment: @BoldBen You're probably right, haha!

Comment: Probably not, but that doesn't mean I'd say it was wrong to do so!

Comment: @KateBunting Okay, so in a sentence like mine, you'd probably not capitalize the term, seeing "baby" as better than "Baby" (though neither would be seen as _wrong_, per se). Is this correct?

Comment: That is what I said.